# How can i make my modal dialog box responsive? As soon as i change the size of my window my modal box break down

Tags: javascript, html, css

As soon as i change the size of the browser window the contents of the modal box goes out of alignment.

**HTML**

```
  <div class='modal'>
  <div class='modal-content'>
  </div>
  </div>
```

This is the CSS of the modal box

```
 .modal {
      display: none; /* Hidden by default */
      position: absolute; /* Stay in place */
      z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%; /* Full width */
      max-width: 100%;
      height: 100%; /* Full height */
      overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
      background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
      padding-top: 60px;
    }

  .modal-content {
      background-color: #ffffff;
      margin: 5% auto 15% auto; /* 5% from the top, 15% from the bottom and 
      centered */
      border: 1px solid #888;
      width: 22%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
      height: 55%;
    }
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to include the HTML parts that are essential to answering this question. Please **[edit]** the question and add it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace relative height and width (%) with viewport units (vw and vh) like this:

```
.modal {
      display: none; /* Hidden by default */
      position: absolute; /* Stay in place */
      z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100vw; /* Full width */
      max-width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh; /* Full height */
      overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
      background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
      padding-top: 60px;
    }

  .modal-content {
      background-color: #ffffff;
      margin: 5% auto 15% auto; /* 5% from the top, 15% from the bottom and 
      centered */
      border: 1px solid #888;
      width: 22vw; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
      height: 55vw;
    }
```

Here is a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dh79rmsp/1/).

Comment: It worked Thanks a lot